# Picture link not working when inside a block

Tags: html, css

would you know why my picture link doesn't work when inside a container (the picture is the white triangle on the right side)? Note that it works fine when outside this block.
Thanks
[image]

CSS:

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.block img {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a z-index issue. Difficult to tell with given info. Please replicate issue on fiddle or provide link to problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this CSS should fix your issue:

```
.arrow-circle{
   position:relative;
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think .block is coming up on the image.. set z-index of image very high . or do this one.

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had done this using inpect element on chrome ..
and link worked...

```
#touchPointContainer {
position: relative;
height: 600px;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is not supported by IE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a z-index issue since the position of .block is relative. However tough point out the issue with the very little info given.. provide some deatils or jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that #touchPointContainer is positioned over the button. The suggested "pointer-events: none;" solution is a firefox hack that is not widely supported.

The z-index solution was the correct one, but for z-index to work you have to add position:relative to the element so Gurpreet Singh nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

The image needs to be given a positioning context so that the Z-index will apply

```
.block img {
float: right;
margin-left: 40px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 100; /* probably any number more than 1 will do */
}
```